# Magento 2.2.3 - CSS and JS not loading on browser

Tags: javascript, css, magento2.2.3

[image]

Hello,

I'm facing an issue that my CSS files are not loading since I made changes in theme table on my DB. I have changed TYPE from 1 to 0 on my theme row in order to load my default_head_blocks.xml (in theme directory). I know this is a very common question, maybe a duplicate question. But none of the solutions works for me.

I have tried following things:

All Magento commands from config:import, setup:upgrade, static:content to cache:flush.
I do have .htaccess file in my pub/static folder.
My 'rewrite_module of apache' is enable.
My folder has 777 permission.
I remove comments from my CSS file and tried minify version as well.

Probably, someone marked my question as a duplicate but I have tried almost every solution available on the Google and none of them works. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As per your screenshot, Your locale is German. You should run below command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy de_DE pl_PL en_US  
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my question. I did all the commands.

Comment: This command is different, please check properly. It's for deploy locale wise theme

Comment: Since I have 3 store views: I have tried in this way

php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento -f setup:static-content:deploy en_US de_DE pl_PL
php bin/magento cache:clean

Comment: Check my updated answer and check for same.

Comment: Ok, so you mean DE first, Ok I'll try. Hope this will make any difference

Comment: So I have tried with that sequence, but no luck. Anything else please.
But now I'm geeting "Refused to apply style from 'link' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled."

Comment: Try this remove all files and folders from pub/static accept .htaccess file then you should run below command : rm -rf var/cache/ ,  php bin/magento setup:upgrade, php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy clean and flush cache. Hope this will help you,

Comment: I've already tried this as well. No luck

Comment: Did you checked .htaccess file in pub/static folder? I guess you have deleted.